# Process returned value in afterExecuteRoute

Tags: php, phalcon

I want to do something with the returnedValue of a controller and action in phalcon here is my code:

```
 public function afterExecuteRoute(Dispatcher $dispatcher){
      $controllerName = $dispatcher->getControllerName();
      $actionName = $dispatcher-> getActionName ();
      $return = $dispatcher->getReturnedValue();
 }
```

$return have this value:

```
Phalcon\Http\Response Object(
  [_sent:protected] => 
  [_content:protected] => "{\"_meta\":{\"status\":\"SUCCESS\",\"count\":2}}"
  [_headers:protected] => Phalcon\Http\Response\Headers Object
      (
          [_headers:protected] => Array
              (
                  [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
              )

      )

  [_cookies:protected] => 
  [_file:protected] => 
  [_dependencyInjector:protected] => 
  [_statusCodes:protected] => 
)
```

How can I get the _meta->status value if it says that

```
Cannot access protected property Phalcon\Http\Response::$_content
```

Comment: i think you can use `$obj->getContent()` method

Comment: Thank you Chetan!! :D I can now do anything what I want with the content!! :D THANKS!!